# Write original Camel message to file

Tags: apache-camel

New to camel and was wondering, given the following route below, how do I store the original message that came into the route in order to log it. So in my when condition below, I call a bean method and if the method returns true, I want to write the original message to a file. This example below instead wants to write the response from the bean call and not the original message that came into the route.

I was thinking about using a setProperty like this below, but then I am not sure how to write this out using the file component?

```
<setProperty propertyName="origInData">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
</setProperty>
```

Any advise would be great. Thanks

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:processOrders"/>
    <bean method="isMaster" ref="mybean"/>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body} == true</simple>
            <to uri="file:c:/out/messages/?fileExist=Append&amp;fileName=messages.txt"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <log message="********* I'M IN SLAVE MODE - DO NOTHING"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a method call (calling a method on a bean) as the predicate in the content based router, eg use `<method>`

```
<choice>
  <when>
    <method method="isMaster" ref="mybean"/>
    ...
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    ...
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Camel supports any kind of predicate to be used, not only the simple language.

Comment: Claus changing this to a method call instead did the trick, but I am sure setProperty would have worked as well as Petter mentioned. Your the Man! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Set a property with the original input. Then, when you need to write it out, bring it back to the message body using something like this:

```
<setBody><simple>${property.origInData}</simple></setBody>
```